# SaltStack: Highstate top.sls files execution when merging strategy is "same"

Tags: salt-stack

In my /etc/salt/master I have the following options set:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
  dev:
    - /srv/salt/dev
```

AND

```
top_file_merging_strategy: same
default_top: base
```

I have a `top.sls` for base(`/srv/salt/top.sls`) environment, which goes:

```
base:
  '*':
    - files
```

Where `files.sls` in defined in `/srv/salt`
And one `top.sls` for dev(`/srv/salt/dev/top.sls`) environment, which goes:

```
dev:
  'saltMinion1':
    - django
  'saltMinion2':
    - MySQL
```

Where `django.sls` and `MySQL.sls` are defined in `/srv/salt/dev/`.
Now if I call:

```
salt '*' state.highstate
```

When I am using **top_file_merging_strategy: merge**, then both base and dev environment are getting applied to my minions, whereas for this scenario, I am using **top_file_merging_strategy: same**, ONLY base environment is getting applied. 
 But according to [Salt documentation: Top File](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html#scenario-3-no-environment-specified-top-file-merging-strategy-is-same), both base as well as dev environments should have gotten applied.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are experiencing [this](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/35045). It's been fixed in Salt 2016.11.

Comment: It has been quite sometime since I worked on this, but it seems to be exact case.

Comment: Glad I could help.